# Which Shapefile parts are necessary to convert to geojson?

Tags: shapefile, geojson, convert, dbf, extensions

Which of those files are needed, to be able to convert them to geojson without losing any information?

From what i know:

- *.shp - contains coordinates for lines, points, and other geometries
- *.prj - contains data about projection, that shapefile is using

I don't know what *.dbf and *.shx files are for. Do I need them to convert to geojson?

Comment: You need .dbf - that is the attributes. .shx is just indexes, but they are mandatory part of the shapefile, so you need those too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting to GeoJson, you need the geometry, so the .shp should be sufficient plus the .prj for the projection. The other extensions provide indexing capabilities and attribute table information

[Esri's definitions](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/shapefiles/shapefile-file-extensions.htm) for .shx and .dbf is the following:

> .shx—The index file that stores the index of the feature geometry; required.
>
> .dbf—The dBASE table that stores the attribute information of features; required. There is a one-to-one relationship between geometry and attributes, which is based on record number. Attribute records in the dBASE file must be in the same order as records in the main file.

[image]

Another way to understand those [extensions](http://gisgeography.com/arcgis-shapefile-files-types-extensions/)

> .shx: ESRI and AutoCAD shape index position. This type of file is used to search forward and backwards. Mandatory.
>
> .dbf: Standard database file used to store attribute data and object IDs. .dbf can be opened in Microsoft Access or Excel. Mandatory.

Comment: Depending on the software being used, you would need the .shp and the .shx. For example QGIS or OGR will not open a ShapeFile without the .shx, although in GDAL 2.1 onwards a missing .shx can be generated.